# I do not understand why when selection in the ListView is disappearing

Tags: c#, listview, select, xamarin.android

I want to select one of the items in the ListView and then press the Edit button that does stuff with selected Listview item. But as soon as I move a mouse from the list view the selection disappears. (I test on VS emulator)
I did look for examples on the Internet but they use a different property that does not exist at all.

Here is the partial code of axml:

```xml
    <TableLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="Ingredients List :"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textView1" />
            <Button
                android:text="Edit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editIngerientsButton" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <ListView
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="50px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ingredientsListView"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Here is the code

```cs
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.parsing_recepie);

            ingredientsListView = (ListView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.ingredientsListView);
            ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Ingredient>(this,
                Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, ingredients);
            ingredientsListView.Adapter = arrayAdapter;
            ingredientsListView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;

            editIngredientsButton = (Button) FindViewById(Resource.Id.editIngerientsButton);
            editIngredientsButton.Click += EditIngredientsButtonOnClick;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should custom a **[Adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/populating#implementing-a-listadapter)** for ListView. Adding a selectItem property into Adapter. When item be selected, change the status of item cell.

**ItemSelectedAdapter.cs**:

```
public class ItemSelectedAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
{
    string[] items;
    Activity context;
    public int selectItem = -1;

    public ItemSelectedAdapter(Activity context, string[] items) : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override string this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Length; }
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = items[position];
        if (selectItem == position)
        {
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
        }
        else
        {
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        }

        return view;
    }

    public void setSelectItem(int selectItem)
    {
        this.selectItem = selectItem;
    }
}
```

**SimpleListItem1.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally in **Activity**:

```
ListView listView;
string[] items;
ItemSelectedAdapter itemSelectedAdapter;
Button editButton;


listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
items = new string[] { "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Flower Buds", "Legumes", "Bulbs", "Tubers" };
itemSelectedAdapter= new ItemSelectedAdapter(this, items);
listView.Adapter = itemSelectedAdapter;
listView.ItemClick += ListView_ItemClick;

editButton= FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
editButton.Click += Button2_Click;

private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    itemSelectedAdapter.setSelectItem(e.Position);
    Console.WriteLine("selected is：" + e.Position);
    itemSelectedAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectItemID = (int)homeScreenAdapter.selectItem;
    Console.WriteLine("selected is：" + selectItemID);
    items[selectItemID] = atv_content.Text;
    homeScreenAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what I've asked. A want to have selection in ListView when I press a button. The list itself should do nothing.

Comment: @Tanya Hi, when selecting a list cell , my gif also press a button .Not too understanding your problem, you can show image to explain .I will chek it.

Comment: @Tanya I have updated my gif , if this is your want , I will update code in answer.

Comment: @Tanya Okey , I have updated my answer .If be helpful , thanks for marking in advance.